# Send a continuous stream of data efficiently to a web server in java

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee

I have a Web Server (WebLogic) and I want to send a continuous stream of data (A Json object) to this server. In other words I want to send the same json object again and again with the least time delay. What is the most efficient way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: All in one request or several requests?

Comment: Open a [`Socket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)?

Comment: @Henry - several requests

Comment: And why? do you want to make some kind of load test?